# 1D histogram opencv with double values

Tags: opencv, histogram

I'm trying to create an histogram using opencv. I have an image (32 bit) that came out from a blurring operation, so I just know that the values are in the range [-0.5; 0.5] but I don't know anything else about the starting data.

the problem is that I don't understand how to set the parameters to compute such histogram.
the code I wrote is:

```
int numbins=1000;
float range[]={-0.5, 0.5};
float *ranges[]={range};
CvHistogram *hist=cvCreateHist(1, &numbins, CV_HIST_ARRAY, ranges, 1);
cvCalcHist(&img, hist);
```

were img is the image I want to get the histogram. if I try to print the histogram I just get a black picture, while with the same function I get a correct histogram if use a grayscale 8bit image.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [calcHist](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html?highlight=createhist#void%20cvCalcHist%28IplImage%2a%2a%20image,%20CvHistogram%2a%20hist,%20int%20accumulate,%20const%20CvArr%2a%20mask%29) example? Also, the [camshiftdemo](https://code.ros.org/svn/opencv/trunk/opencv/samples/cpp/camshiftdemo.cpp) makes heavy use of histograms.

Are you normalizing the histogram output with [normalize](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=normalize#cv2.normalize) before display (camshiftdemo shows how to do this)? Values near 0 will appear black when displayed, but when normalized between say 0 and 255 will show up nicely.